# Winsock функции send и recv - где хранятся полученные байты?

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть две синхронные функции в Winsock: send и recv.

send() - отправляет данные на удаленный сервер, а recv - принимает ответ на этот запрос.

Мой вопрос собственно в следующем:

Я вызываю send()..
Далее ставлю к примеру задержку в 20 секунд...
И вызываю recv и получаю данные.

А откуда я получаю данные ? То есть, как это абстрактно происходит ?

-После send(), сервер, отправляет в ответ так же данные и эти данные записываются операционной системой во временный буфер, которая же она сама и создает ? А функцией recv() я извлекаю эти данные из этого временного буфера уже в свой буфер ?

-Если это примерно так, а как тогда принимаются данные ну к примеру огромных размеров типа 4 Гб ? То есть я сделал предположим Sleep() между send и recv на час, и что получается ОС будет в оперативной памяти выделять 4Гб и писать туда данные ?
Или это будет происходить небольшими частями и пока я функцией recv() не извлеку данные из этого временного буфера, ОС не будет принимать данные ?

-Если это примерно так, то как, тогда происходит приемка 4 Гб данных в асинхронной функции WSARecv() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вычитал из Глейзера:

> Для решения проблемы протоколу TCP позволено послать сразу множество
> сегментов, не дожидаясь подтверждения. Однако количество таких
> сегментов не может быть бесконечным, так как возникает другая
> проблема. Когда данные транспортного уровня достигают узла, они
> сохраняются в буфере, пока процесс, связанный с соответствующим
> портом, не извлечет их. В этот момент данные удаляются из буфера.
> Неважно, каким объемом памяти обладает узел, сам буфер имеет некоторый
> фиксированный размер. Легко представить, что сложный процесс на
> медленном процессоре может не справляться с обработкой данных,
> поступающих слишком быстро. То есть когда буфер заполнится, вновь
> прибывающие данные будут отбрасываться. Для протокола TCP это
> означает, что получаемые данные не будут подтверждаться и
> быстродействующий отправитель повторит передачу данных с высокой
> скоростью. Весьма вероятно, что большая часть вновь отправленных
> данных опять будет сброшена, потому что принимающий узел имеет все тот
> же медленный процессор, на котором выполняется все тот же сложный
> процесс. В результате значительная доля трафика будет потеряна, что
> является недопустимым разбазариванием ресурсов Интернета.
>
> Чтобы устранить эту катастрофическую неэффективность, TCP реализует
> процедуру, известную как управление потоком данных (flow control).
> Управление потоком не позволяет быстродействующему узлу «завалить»
> пакетами менее быстродействующего потребителя. Каждый TCP-заголовок
> содержит поле с размером окна приема, значение которого указывает,
> какой объем приемного буфера доступен отправителю пакетов. С его
> помощью принимающая сторона сообщает передающему узлу максимальный
> объем данных, который тот может послать, прежде чем приостановиться в
> ожидании подтверждения.

Непонятно только на каком этапе соединения, точнее на каком этапе вызова Winsock функций происходит обмен данными о:

> ...размере окна приема, значение которого указывает, какой объем
> приемного буфера доступен отправителю пакетов...